# Angular2 I need to get my component to call a function in another component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular2 and I need to get my **service** to call a function in another **component**.

I have **1 service and 1 component**.

I have 1 header component that needs to be called when the service action is complete. This service action is not called from the header service.

I'm using typescript with Angular2 as my tech.

I need a way to simply call a function in another component from my service.

I'm looking for something similar to **Angular1 emit / broadcast.**

The below attempt is based off this example: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

**My attempt:**

Scenario - I need my service to let the header component know when a service function is complete.

**Service:**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()

export class TransactionService{
    private invokeCreditCheckEvent = new Subject<string>();
    invokeCreditCheckEventAnnounced$ = this.invokeCreditCheckEvent.asObservable();

    constructor(){
    }   

    createCredit = (): Promise<boolean> => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                this.invokeCreditCheckEvent.next("updateHeader");   

                resolve(true);  

        });     
    }


}
```

**Component:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {TransactionService} from '../../../services/transactionService/transactionService';
import {Subscription}   from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'HeaderCompanyComponent',
  templateUrl: 'HeaderCompany.component.html'
})

export class HeaderCompanyComponent{ 
  transactionService: TransactionService;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(transactionService: TransactionService){   
      this.transactionService = transactionService;

      this.subscription = transactionService.invokeCreditCheckEventAnnounced$.subscribe(response => {
           console.log("header hit!");
      });
  }  
}
```

**component module:**

```
export * from './headerCompany.component';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HeaderCompanyComponent } from './headerCompany.component';
import { TransactionService } from '../../../services/transactionService/transactionService';

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule, CommonModule],
  declarations: [HeaderCompanyComponent],
  exports: [HeaderCompanyComponent],
  providers: [TransactionService]
})

export class HeaderCompanyModule { }
```

**Outcome:**

Nothing seems to happen.

**What should happen:**

Header component console log should of been hit

Comment: Use a shared service with an observable like explained in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: It doesnt seem to work. I will update my attempt now above. Seems to not hit the other component.

Comment: Please post another comment after you updated.

Comment: Try using a `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject`. `BehaviorSubject` doesn't depend on the event being emitted **after** the subscription.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have updated the question to show my current attempt thats not working

Comment: Where are you providing the `TransactionService` (`@Component(...)` or `@NgModel(...)`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I don't understand the question. I inject TransactionService into the header component.

Comment: But you need to add it to `providers: [...]` somewhere, otherwise it won't be injected.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I just added my component module for the header component

Comment: Did you try `BehaviorSubject`?

Comment: Yeh just tried BehaviorSubject. Nothing happend either.

Comment: I managed to get it working like in my example above. I was just calling the subject from the wrong function. So the above example is correct

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would try: 
Since Subject is an instance of observable, try a getter inside your TransactionService that returns your subject as an observable

```
get invokeCreditCheckEventAnnounced() : Observable<string>{
    return this.invokeCreditCheckEvent;
}
```

Also make sure both the publisher and subscriber are talking to the same TxService instance